# Python 2.7 getting user input and manipulating as string without quotations

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

I want to get a string from a user, and then to manipulate it.

```
testVar = input("Ask user for something.")
```

Is there a way for testVar to be a string without me having the user type his response in quotes?  i.e. "Hello" vs. Hello

If the user types in Hello, I get the following error:

NameError: name 'Hello' is not defined

Comment: [See documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval). As of python 2.7 `input` automatically calls `eval()`

Answer (score 268, accepted):

Use `raw_input()` instead of `input()`:

```
testVar = raw_input("Ask user for something.")
```

`input()` actually evaluates the input as Python code.  I suggest to never use it.  `raw_input()` returns the verbatim string entered by the user.

Comment: Although for anyone reading this using Python **3**, `input` now works this way, and raw_input is gone.

Comment: What situation would you want to let the user insert python code into your own code?

Comment: @JFA: I don't think `input()` is a useful function, and I don't recommend using it.

Answer (score 14):

The function `input` will also evaluate the data it just read as python code, which is not really what you want.

The generic approach would be to treat the user input (from `sys.stdin`) like any other file. Try

```
import sys
sys.stdin.readline()
```

If you want to keep it short, you can use `raw_input` which is the same as `input` but omits the evaluation.

Comment: also, if you are writing an interactive program, consider importing `readline` -- this will give features similar to bash (history out-of-the-box, auto-completion will require some legwork)

Comment: Well done! I have used the same function for ages and it has ever worked well.

Comment: This is the best answer for both Python 2 and 3 compatibility. It works in both versions. At the end, of course, the end-of-line character is also added (in Linux is it `\n`), which does not interfere at all. In Python 3, the `raw_input` function is replaced by the `input` function, but for compatibility reasons it is a completely different function ! In Python 3, the `input` function also allows to insert a string, but in Python 2, the `input` function does not allow to insert a string (only the `raw_input` function allow the string, which is already removed in Python 3, unfortunately).

Answer (score 11):

We can use the `raw_input()` function in Python 2 and the `input()` function in Python 3.
By default the input function takes an input in string format. For other data type you have to cast the user input.

In Python 2 we use the `raw_input()` function. It waits for the user to type some input and press `return` and we need to store the value in a variable by casting as our desire data type. Be careful when using type casting

```
x = raw_input("Enter a number: ") #String input

x = int(raw_input("Enter a number: ")) #integer input

x = float(raw_input("Enter a float number: ")) #float input

x = eval(raw_input("Enter a float number: ")) #eval input
```

In Python 3 we use the input() function which returns a user input value.

```
x = input("Enter a number: ") #String input
```

If you enter a string, int, float, eval it will take as string input

```
x = int(input("Enter a number: ")) #integer input
```

If you enter a string for int cast `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:`

```
x = float(input("Enter a float number: ")) #float input
```

If you enter a string for float cast `ValueError: could not convert string to float`

```
x = eval(input("Enter a float number: ")) #eval input
```

If you enter a string for eval cast `NameError: name ' ' is not defined`
 Those error also applicable for Python 2.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to use input instead of raw_input in python 2.x,then this trick will come handy

```
    if hasattr(__builtins__, 'raw_input'):
      input=raw_input
```

After which,

```
testVar = input("Ask user for something.")
```

will work just fine.

Answer (score 2):

```
testVar = raw_input("Ask user for something.")
```

Answer (score 0):

My Working code with fixes:

```
import random
import math
print "Welcome to Sam's Math Test"
num1= random.randint(1, 10)
num2= random.randint(1, 10)
num3= random.randint(1, 10)
list=[num1, num2, num3]
maxNum= max(list)
minNum= min(list)
sqrtOne= math.sqrt(num1)

correct= False
while(correct == False):
    guess1= input("Which number is the highest? "+ str(list) + ": ")
    if maxNum == guess1:
        print("Correct!")
        correct = True
    else:
        print("Incorrect, try again")

correct= False
while(correct == False):
guess2= input("Which number is the lowest? " + str(list) +": ")
if minNum == guess2:
     print("Correct!")
     correct = True
else:
    print("Incorrect, try again")

correct= False
while(correct == False):
    guess3= raw_input("Is the square root of " + str(num1) + " greater than or equal to 2? (y/n): ")
    if sqrtOne >= 2.0 and str(guess3) == "y":
        print("Correct!")
        correct = True
    elif sqrtOne < 2.0 and str(guess3) == "n":
        print("Correct!")
        correct = True
    else:
        print("Incorrect, try again")

print("Thanks for playing!")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my work around to fail safe in case if i will need to move to python 3 in future.

```
def _input(msg):
  return raw_input(msg)
```

Answer (score -7):

The issue seems to be resolved in Python version 3.4.2.

```
testVar = input("Ask user for something.")
```

Will work fine.

Comment: Python 3.x `input` is equivalent to Python 2.x `raw_input` (see https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#builtins); this is an issue specific to 2.x.