# Creating a Python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, numbers, key

Is it possible to create a dictionary like this?

```
data = {(136-00000-0001 : 072-00000-0001,072-00000-0002,072-00000-0003),
        (136-00000-0002 : 072-00000-0002,072-00000-0003,072-00000-0004)}

text = input("Put your 072-XXXXX-XXXX number in here: ")
wrapper =[]

for number in text:
 if number in data.keys()
  wrapper.append(data[number]

 for w in wrapper:
  print(w, end=" ")
```

I have a wrapper called 136-xxxxx-xxxx where 3*072-xxxxx-xxxx are in it.
All I want to do is, asking for a 072-xxxxx-xxxx number and the program is giving me
the Wrapper number of it back.

For example:

- asking for 072-00000-0004
- answer -> it´s inside 136-00000-0002

The only way I know is, for example that morse thing, where
`morse = {"a":".-", "b":"-..."`, but is there a way like this for my example at the top?

Comment: your dict syntax is incorrect, you cannot store multiple values for a key unless you use some container like a list, tuple etc..

Comment: That´s what im asking for :/ How do i fix it so i can use it?

Comment: ok I will add an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python 2.x:

```
>>> data = {"136-00000-0001":["072-00000-0001","072-00000-0002","072-00000-0003"],"136-00000-0002":["072-00000-0002","072-00000-0003","072-00000-0004"]}
>>> text = raw_input("Put your 072-XXXXX-XXXX number in here: ")
Put your 072-XXXXX-XXXX number in here: 072-00000-0004
>>> for d in data:
...     if text in data[d]:
...         print d
136-00000-0002
```

And for Python 3 you have to use `input()` instead of  `raw_input()` and `print()` as a function.

```
>>> data = {"136-00000-0001":["072-00000-0001","072-00000-0002","072-00000-0003"],"136-00000-0002":["072-00000-0002","072-00000-0003","072-00000-0004"]}
>>> text = input("Put your 072-XXXXX-XXXX number in here: ")
Put your 072-XXXXX-XXXX number in here: 072-00000-0004
>>> for d in data:
...     if text in data[d]:
...         print(d)
136-00000-0002
```

Comment: why would you have to enter a string in quotes?

Comment: because python will treat `text` as a number

Comment: I did and I also added the sample.

Comment: for python 3 that the OP is obviously using?

Comment: In where the OP is telling us that he is using Python 3 ? And I don't think that will become a reason for a downvote.

Comment: Your answer is wrong, you have not taken into account that the OP is using python 3 syntax so along with incorrect instruction your code will not run because it has syntax errors.

Comment: I **did know** that Python 2 code will not run in Python 3.
But the OP's syntax is wrong with either Python 2 or 3, so I don't get the point why are you saying that he is using python 3 ?

Comment: print is a function in python 3 and a statement in  python 2, the OP is using it as a function and I doubt he/she is using `from future import..`

Comment: Okay, the OP is using print as a function and _maybe_ he/she wrote it in Python 3. So while your answer also contains `print data.values()`, I can say that your answer is wrong, incorrect instruction and will not run :) 
Your reason for a down vote is not clear enough.

Comment: if the OP was using python 2.7, he/she should use raw_input. You like the OP don't seem to fully understand what you are doing so for future instances when anybody searches SO and comes on this question,your answer would not be a good example of how to proceed with the code.  Is that clear enough?

Comment: (1) In this case and in python 2.7 he/she can use input() as well as raw_input()

(2) I do understand what i'm doing and I don't have to mention it to you while answering to the OP.

(3) You pointed that maybe the OP used Python 3, but gave him a answer which will not run in Python 3.

(4) At last, I admit that my answer may won't correct for Python 3 and not specify it was my fault. See answer updated.

Comment: mine was a typo, your errors are from not knowing what you are doing, you just put  "may wrong with Python 3", it is certainly wrong syntax for python 3 and why on earth would you use input, have a look at this question and maybe you will learn something: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4960208/python-2-7-getting-user-input-and-manipulating-as-string-without-quotations.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to store multiple values for your keys in a list,tuple etc.. You cannot have more than one value for a key.

```
data = {"136-00000-0001" : ["072-00000-0001","072-00000-0002","072-00000-0003"],"136-00000-0002" : ["072-00000-0002","072-00000-0003","072-00000-0004"]}
print ( data.values())

[['072-00000-0001', '072-00000-0002', '072-00000-0003'], ['072-00000-0002', '072-00000-0003', '072-00000-0004']]
```

To append to a keys values:

```
data["136-00000-0001"].append("whatever")
```

Check if value is in the dict and print the key,value pair.:

```
In [5]: for k,v in data.items():
            if "072-00000-0004" in v:
                print (k,v)
   ...:         
136-00000-0002 ['072-00000-0002', '072-00000-0003', '072-00000-0004']
```

Use strings if you want use the format `072-00000-0002` will  give an error  `SyntaxError: invalid token`
.

Comment: *as - will obviously subtract..* or `SyntaxError` in Python 3.x... Either that or the OP has a future import for their `print(w, end=" ")`

Comment: @JonClements, edited. I very much doubt the OP is using future import