# Python user data check

Tags: python

I have a program that gets user's input and then asks whether the information is correct or not. However, when the user has finished entering information, I get an error with this code:

```
#Welcome
print("Welcome to the game!\n")


def data():
    #Age
    age = int(input("Enter your age: "))
    #Gender
    gen = input("Enter your gender: ")
    #email
    mail = input("Enter your email: ")
    #username
    name = input("Enter your name: ")
    return (age, gen, mail, name)

def datacheck():
    print("Your information:\n")
    print("Age: ", age, "\n")
    print("Gender: ", gen, "\n")
    print("Email: ", mail, "\n")
    print("Username: ", name, "\n")
    yn = input("Is it correct? Yes or No: ")
    if yn == "Yes":
        print("Hello, ", name)
    if yn == "No":
        data()
        #Array to variables
        age = data[0]
        gen = data[1]
        mail = data[2]
        name = data[3]
        #datacheck
        datacheck()


data = data()


#Array to Variable.
age = data[0]
gen = data[1]
mail = data[2]
name = data[3]
#datacheck
datacheck()
```

The error  I get is:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/Users/joe/Documents/test123.py", line 48, in 
>       datacheck()   File "/Users/joe/Documents/test123.py", line 20, in datacheck
>       print("Age: ", age, "\n") UnboundLocalError: local variable 'age' referenced before assignment

There is no error if I type but the re-entering of info doesn't work:

```
#Welcome
print("Welcome to the game!\n")


def data():
    #Age
    age = int(input("Enter your age: "))
    #Gender
    gen = input("Enter your gender: ")
    #email
    mail = input("Enter your email: ")
    #username
    name = input("Enter your name: ")
    return (age, gen, mail, name)

def datacheck():
    print("Your information:\n")
    print("Age: ", age, "\n")
    print("Gender: ", gen, "\n")
    print("Email: ", mail, "\n")
    print("Username: ", name, "\n")
    yn = input("Is it correct? Yes or No: ")
    if yn == "Yes":
        print("Hello, ", name)
    if yn == "No":
        data()
        #datacheck
        datacheck()


data = data()


#Array to Variable.
age = data[0]
gen = data[1]
mail = data[2]
name = data[3]
#datacheck
datacheck()
```

How would I get it so that the user can re-enter their information (data function)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a [scoping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-python-scoping-rules) issue.

Furthermore, I think you might want to consider being [object oriented](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html). That is, if my assumptions are right about your use of the user data. Instead of holding your user's attributes in a bunch of arrays (lists), you can hold the user's attributes in something called an [object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_%28computer_science%29). I mean, if your user ends up having 2,000 attributes, do you want to have to remember what attribute number represents their eye color so you can reference it in a list? Probably not. haha

This approach might make your code easier to use/reuse and more organized for the future:

```
class User():
    """A class representing a user.

    defaults set.
    """

    def __init__(self, data={'age': 1,
                             'gender': 'x',
                             'mail': 'user@default',
                             'name': 'User'}):

        self.data = data
        self.age = self.data['age']
        self.gender = self.data['gender']
        self.mail = self.data['mail']
        self.name = self.data['name']

    def __str__(self):
        """The string representation of a User object."""

        return self.name


    def get_age(self):
        """Return the user's age."""

        return self.age

    def get_gender(self):
        """Return the user's gender."""

        return self.gen

    def get_mail(self):
        """Return the user's email address."""

        return self.mail

    def get_name(self):
        """Return the user's name."""

        return self.name

    def get_data(self):
        """Return a dictionary containing a User's info."""

        return self.data

if __name__=="__main__":

    user_data = {} # will contain our data

    # ask for user input
    for key in ["age", "gender", "mail", "name"]:
        user_data[key] = raw_input("Enter your %s: " % key)

    # Store user input data in an object
    user = User(data=user_data)

    print user.get_data() # prints a dictionary containing user values
```

Comment: Thank you. In future, I will look into using this. :)

Answer (score 2):

age, gen, mail, name are `local variables` in both `data()` and `datacheck()`, those variables `scope` is the method they belong to.  You have to define those variables as `global` or you pass the variables/tuple object from one method to another.

Based on your logic, you need to pass your tuple object into `datacheck()`, modify it to `datacheck(tuple)`, I tested it as follows:

```
hzhang@dell-work ~/PycharmProjects/Test $ cat test.py 
#Welcome
print("Welcome to the game!\n")


def data():
    #Age
    age = int(input("Enter your age: "))
    #Gender
    gen = input("Enter your gender: ")
    #email
    mail = input("Enter your email: ")
    #username
    name = input("Enter your name: ")
    return (age, gen, mail, name)


def datacheck(data):
    age = data[0]
    gen = data[1]
    mail = data[2]
    name = data[3]

    print("Your information:\n")
    print("Age: ", age, "\n")
    print("Gender: ", gen, "\n")
    print("Email: ", mail, "\n")
    print("Username: ", name, "\n")
    yn = input("Is it correct? Yes or No: ")
    if yn == "Yes":
        print("Hello, ", name)
    if yn == "No":
        values = data()
        #datacheck
        datacheck(values)


data = data()

#Array to Variable.
age = data[0]
gen = data[1]
mail = data[2]
name = data[3]
#datacheck
datacheck(data)hzhang@dell-work ~/PycharmProjects/Test $ python test.py 
Welcome to the game!

Enter your age: 22
Enter your gender: "male"
Enter your email: "hi@email.com"
Enter your name: "haifzhan"
Your information:

('Age: ', 22, '\n')
('Gender: ', 'male', '\n')
('Email: ', 'hi@email.com', '\n')
('Username: ', 'haifzhan', '\n')
Is it correct? Yes or No: "Yes" 
('Hello, ', 'haifzhan')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variables are not global, you need to pass them to the function or declare them global.

Also raw_input should be used instead of input for strings as noted here: [Python 2.7 getting user input and manipulating as string without quotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4960208/python-2-7-getting-user-input-and-manipulating-as-string-without-quotations)

```
#Welcome
print("Welcome to the game!\n")


def data():
    #Age
    age = raw_input(input("Enter your age: "))
    #Gender
    gen = raw_input("Enter your gender: ")
    #email
    mail = raw_input("Enter your email: ")
    #username
    name = raw_input("Enter your name: ")
    return (age, gen, mail, name)

def datacheck(age, gen, mail, name):
    print("Your information:\n")
    print("Age: ", age, "\n")
    print("Gender: ", gen, "\n")
    print("Email: ", mail, "\n")
    print("Username: ", name, "\n")
    yn = raw_input("Is it correct? Yes or No: ")
    if yn == "Yes":
        print("Hello, ", name)
    if yn == "No":
        data()
        #datacheck
        datacheck(age, gen, mail, name)


data = data()


#Array to Variable.
age = data[0]
gen = data[1]
mail = data[2]
name = data[3]
#datacheck
datacheck(age, gen, mail, name)
```

Works for me.

Comment: change in the " if yn == "No":" part  datacheck() to datacheck(age, gen, mail, name)

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the variables from the first function to the second on before trying to use them

```
#Welcome
print("Welcome to the game!\n")


def data():
    age = int(input("Enter your age: "))
    gen = str(input("Enter your gender: "))
    mail = str(input("Enter your email: "))
    name = str(input("Enter your name: "))
    return (age, gen, mail, name)

def datacheck():
    age, gen, mail, name = data()
    print("Your information:\n")
    print("Age: %s\n"%(age))
    print("Gender: %s\n"%(gen))
    print("Email: %s\n"%(mail))
    print("Username: %s\n"%(name))
    yn = input("Is it correct? Yes or No: ")
    if yn == "Yes":
        print("Hello, ", name)
    if yn == "No":
        datacheck()

#datacheck
datacheck()
```

Comment: Wont this infinite loop?