# problems with int() in a python encryption programm

Tags: python, python-2.7, int

I need to make sure that the input shift for the cypher is a integer. How would I go around making sure that it is, so far when ever I use the int() variable round any of the inputs, it generates an error even when I do put an integer in.

Here is the code, it is written and compiled with 2.7.6

```
 import re

def caesar(plain_text, shift):
    cipherText = ''
    for ch in plain_text:
      stayInAlphabet = ord(ch) + shift
      if ch.islower():
        if stayInAlphabet > ord('z'):
          stayInAlphabet -=26
        elif stayInAlphabet < ord('a'):
          stayInAlphabet += 26
      elif ch.isupper():
        if stayInAlphabet > ord('Z'):
          stayInAlphabet -= 26
        elif stayInAlphabet < ord('A'):
          stayInAlphabet += 26
      finalLetter = chr(stayInAlphabet)
      cipherText += finalLetter
    print(cipherText)
    return cipherText

selection = input ("encrypt/decrypt ")
if selection == 'encrypt':
  plainText = input("What is your plaintext? ")
  shift = (int(input("What is your shift? ")))%26
  caesar(plainText, shift)

else:
  plainText = input("What is your plaintext? ")
  shift = ((int(input("What is your shift? ")))%26)*-1
  caesar(plainText, shift)
```

Comment: Hi Alexander! It will help people answer your question if you post the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For python 2.7, you want to use `raw_input` instead of `input`. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4960208/python-2-7-getting-user-input-and-manipulating-as-string-without-quotations) for more detail.