# Python - calling 2 functions from another python file in main()

Tags: python

I created 2 different python files.
The first file named "game.py" has the code:

```
h = int(input("Pick number 1 or 2: "))

def game():

    if h == 1:
        print ("You lose!")
    if h == 2:
        print ("You win!")

def play_again():

    rounds = input("Play again? (Y/N): ")
    if rounds == "Y":
        game()
    if rounds == "NO":
        print ("Game Over")
```

As shown, I have 2 functions in this file.

Then I created another file with my main function that calls these 2 functions. The following is the code inside it:

```
import game

def main():

    game.game()

    game.play_again()

main()
```

When I run this on the console, it prints "Pick number 1 or 2: ". But if I run it again, it prints "Play again? (Y/N): ".

How do I fix this so that it only prints "Pick number 1 or 2 : " whenever I run the code?

Comment: How do you run this on the console? What do you type to start the program?

Comment: I'm using Spyder 3.4 so I just have to run it. I don't have to type anything. @Robᵩ

Comment: The `input` line is executed only during the first `import game` of each Python session. I guess that Spyder doesn't start a new Python session when you "just run it." How to fix it depends upon why that code is there. Tell us more about why you placed that code outside of a function.

Comment: I have run your code using spyder and it works fine, where do you see the output when you run your code?

Answer (score 0):

maingame.py:

```
import game

game.game()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("maingame.py is being run directly")
else:
    print("maingame.py is being imported into another module")
```

game.py:

```
def game():
    h = input("Pick number 1 or 2:\n")
    if h == 1:
        print("You lose!")
    if h == 2:
        print("You win!")
    play_again()

def play_again():
    rounds = raw_input("Play again? (Y/N): ") # just use input() for python3
    if rounds == 'Y':
        game()
    if rounds == 'N':
        print("Game Over")
```

See also: [What does if __name__ == "__main__": do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do)

and: [Python 2.7 getting user input and manipulating as string without quotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4960208/python-2-7-getting-user-input-and-manipulating-as-string-without-quotations)

You can delete the three bottom lines from maingame.py but you *should* read the associated link to understand what `if __name__ == "__main__":` does and why. Normally you would just write:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

And this will ensure that your file will run, beginning with main(), when called from the command line.