# Error when inputting Date Python on Visual Studio 2015

Tags: python, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I'm getting an error

> must be string, not int

for these two lines of code.

```
userInput = input("Please enter your birthday (mm/dd/yyyy)")
birthday = datetime.datetime.strptime(userInput, '%m/%d/%Y').date()
```

The problem seems to be with variable `userInput` , but from the examples and tutorials I saw online, it should be working.

[image: Screenschot]

How to fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
userInput = input("Please enter your birthday (mm/dd/yyyy)")
```

to

```
userInput = raw_input("Please enter your birthday (mm/dd/yyyy)")
```

because the your original input is calculating the date as if it's carrying out a division.

EDIT: I don't use Visual Studio, but just in case, this is how I figured it out.

1. The error is telling me that the userInput is returning an int instead of a string, so I checked it by running the code for userInput in a Python console.
2. I checked what userInput collected:

   print userInput
3. It returned 0, so I realized it was doing an integer division.
4. I googled "python string user input" and it returned a link to [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4960208/python-2-7-getting-user-input-and-manipulating-as-string-without-quotations), which was where I got the answer.

Answer (score 1):

`input` handles user's input as code. So if you enter say, `25/09/2015`, Python handles it as division of 25 by 9 and then by 2015. You can `print userInput` and see that it is `0`.
You have to input date in quotation marks (as string) or use `raw_input`.

*BTW printing variables that seem to cause problems is a good debug method.*

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be some inconsistencies in Python 2.7 and Python 3 versions. I was using Python 2.7 while the tutorials I followed was using Python 3+, where `input()` works like it should in this case.