# How to use a shortcut for the (or) statement in python

Tags: function, python-3.x

```
def checkclas(x):
   while x == "A" or "B" or "C" is not True:
      x = input("You have to choose one of the three classes: ").upper() 
      return x

clas = input("which class are you in? ").upper()
clas = checkclas(clas)
print (clas)
```

I tried to solve the problem with this code, but I couldn't. I want the program to check if the input class is valid, and then to print it, but it keeps going in the while loop forever, even though I input the right class. I think the problem is with the (or) statement. If anyone has got a solution please help me, this is for my computer science assessment, and the code has to be efficient.

Comment: `while x not in "ABC":`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I test one variable against multiple values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-do-i-test-one-variable-against-multiple-values)

Comment: Not that your current statement evaluates as: x == "A", or "B", or "C" is not True. With your way, it should have been `(x == "A" or x == "B" or x == "C") is not True`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but I have tried your solution it is not working.

Comment: "It is not working" is very vague. The more you tell us, the more we can help. Also, you don't have to say `is not True` its redundent. You can just say `while not x == "A" or x == "B" or x == "C":`to get the same effect of your post

Comment: @AustinWBryan In your solution only when I type (A) it breaks the loop, but when I type (B) or (C), it will continue.

Comment: Thank you @AustinWBryan, I have developed your solution by making brackets around the while loop statment, and I have solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need an `if` statement wrapped around your `while` statement. See the code below. (Note that the user input has to be in string format.)

```
def checkclas(x):
   if x not in ("A", "B", "C"):
      while x not in ("A", "B", "C"):
          x = input("You have to choose one of the three classes:     ").upper()
      return x
   else:
      return x

clas = input("which class are you in? ").upper()
clas = checkclas(clas)
print (clas)
```

EDIT:

Addressed redundant if-else statement and provided a more natural (and appropriate - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4960208/python-2-7-getting-user-input-and-manipulating-as-string-without-quotations)) way to input strings.

```
def checkclas(x):
    while x not in ("A", "B", "C"):
        x = raw_input("You have to choose one of the three classes: ").upper()
    return x

clas = raw_input("which class are you in? ").upper()
clas = checkclas(clas)
print (clas)
```

Comment: There is some redundancy here. You're checking for `x not in ("A", "B", "C")` twice. Therefore, if OP were to add in "D", he would have to add it in two places, instead of just one.

Comment: Thank you @Imad Ali , your code is helped me to make my code more efficient. I have just deleted the if and else statements, because there was no need for it.

Comment: @AustinWBryan - Thanks for addressing the redundancy.

Comment: @Y.Hasan - happy to help.

Answer (score -2):

If you have control over the definitions of A, B, and C I recommend using [Python Inheritance](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html).

```
class MyBaseObject(object):
    pass

class A(MyBaseObject):
    pass

class B(MyBaseObject):
    pass

class C(MyBaseObject):
    pass

...
x = A()
if isinstance(x, MyBaseObject):
    ...
```

Comment: This is completely overkill.

Comment: @AustinWBryan I proposed this because OP said the input was choosing between classes, it seems OP was not speaking of [classes](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html), but rather about a set of strings.

Comment: My bad. I tried to undownvote you, but it said my vote is locked unless this post is edited. But yes, his "class" idea confused me as well, while reading another post. He should have been more clear.

Comment: @AustinWBryan no hard feelings :)