# Syntax error when reading data in with input()

Tags: python

I've been trying to code a simple calculator on python GUI but I'm getting a syntax error message. I am new to programming so I am unsure what do.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kmart3223\Desktop\Martinez_K_Lab1.py", line 126, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\kmart3223\Desktop\Martinez_K_Lab1.py", line 111, in main
    operation = input("What operations should we do ( +, -, /, *):")
  File "<string>", line 1
    +
    ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

Code

```
def main():
    operation = input("What operations should we do ( +, -, /, *):")
    if(operation != '+' and operation != '-' and operation != '/' and operation != '*'):
        print ("chose an operation")
    else:
        variable1 = int(input("Enter digits"))
        variable2 = int(input("Enter other digits"))
        if (operation == "+"):
            print (add(variable1, variable2))
        elif (operation == "-"):
            print (sub(variable1, variable2))
        elif (operaion == "*"):
            print (mul(variable1, variable2))
        else:
            print (div(variable1, variable2))
main()
```

Comment: Python 2 or Python 3?

Comment: You are using Python 2. Use `raw_input` and not `input`

Comment: Close reason Typo, resolved in a manner ....

Comment: @Drew Duplicate too [Python 2.7 getting user input and manipulating as string without quotations](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4960208)

Answer (score 2):

if you are using python 2x use `raw_input()`

```
>>> input()         # only takes python expression
>>> input()
+
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1
    +
    ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
>>> input()
'+'                 # string ok
'+'
>>> input()
7                   # integer ok
7
>>> raw_input()              # Takes input as string
+
'+'
```

Comment: Yup. To help OP it would probably help to replicate their error in that same context you are answering to help them visualize what is going on. Use `+`, for example as input instead of `hello`

Comment: @idjaw updated, thanks

Comment: Specifically, `input()` tries to evaluate the input as if it was a python expression. So passing `5+7` in the input will return 12. And just as in a normal script, just writing `+` is invalid syntax.

Answer (score 0):

use `raw_input()` instead of `input()`

`input()` interprets the data you enter as a Python expression. `raw_input()` on the other hand returns the string you enter.