# print error with Python

Tags: python

I have this code

```
import time
total = int(input("What has the total come to?"))
times = float(input("What percent tip are you going to leave? Example:       1.15     = 15%"))
time.sleep(1)
people = int(input("How many people are there?"))
time.sleep(1)
tip=total*times
share=tip/people
print("The total is:", round(tip, 3))
print("You all have to pay", round(share, 3), "Each")
time.sleep(1)
taxi = 0.45
home = str(input("Are you taking a Taxi home?"))
if home in ("Yes", "YES", "yes"):
    distance = int(input("How many miles do you have to go?")
    ammount=taxi*distance
    print("Your total for your Journey is", ammount)
```

I'm working on a taxi calculator and keep getting this error "Invalid syntax". The part that calculates the tip works.

Comment: Please format your code. After you start your if, you definitly need to indent.

Comment: Which version of Python are you using? Also, please format your code as a block by highlighting it all and using the code formatting button (`{}`), making sure the indentation reflects your actual script, and post the full error.

Comment: Please format your code properly first to make it more readable. Thanks!

Comment: note enough parentheses here `int(input("How many miles do you have to go?")`

Comment: Is this your actual code? Check your indentation.

Comment: Add a closing brace to `distance = int(input("How many miles do you have to go?")` i.e. `distance = int(input("How many miles do you have to go?"))`. Often if you forget something like this the error is flagged against the next line

Comment: Check [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4960208/python-2-7-getting-user-input-and-manipulating-as-string-without-quotations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4960208/python-2-7-getting-user-input-and-manipulating-as-string-without-quotations), which advises on the use of `raw_input()` for Python 2.x series, as your program relies on the user being aware (how if not reading the source?) that he/she should input a string with double quotes otherwise one would get the error _NameError: name 'YES' is not defined_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a parenthesis.It should be :

```
distance = int(input("How many miles do you have to go?"))
```

So it would end up looking like this:

```
import time

total = int(input("What has the total come to?"))
times = float(input("What percent tip are you going to leave? Example:       1.15     = 15%"))
time.sleep(1)
people = int(input("How many people are there?"))
time.sleep(1)
tip = total * times
share = tip / people
print("The total is:", round(tip, 3))
print("You all have to pay", round(share, 3), "Each")
time.sleep(1)
taxi = 0.45
home = str(input("Are you taking a Taxi home?"))
if home in ("Yes", "YES", "yes"):
  distance = int(input("How many miles do you have to go?"))
  ammount = taxi * distance
  print("Your total for your Journey is", ammount)
```