# AttributeError 'int' object has no attribute isdigit in ipython in ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, ipython

```
def input_base():
    print('please enter the number')
    base = input("Number : ")
    while not base.isdigit():
       print("It`s not integer")
       base = input("R.Number : ")
    return base 
    ...
```

This is my code and the error is:

> AttributeError : 'int' object has no attribute 'isdigit'

I don't know how I could fix this code. I think, I should install some application, such a `python-numpy`, inside Ubuntu...
Is that right?

Comment: Use `raw_input` instead of `input`.

Comment: `isdigit` is a string method.  Numbers don't have this method.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4960208/python-2-7-getting-user-input-and-manipulating-as-string-without-quotations

Comment: @hpaulj The question is, of course, why 'input' returns a number, and why 'raw_input' fixes this.

Comment: This code works in python3

Comment: Isn`t there commend 'isdigit' in ipython?? wow... this cord really works in python3!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using python2 therefore you have two functions `input` and `raw_input`. The difference being that `input` calls `eval` on the inputted string. This turns it from a string to whatever python would interpret it as when input as a script or at the REPL.

For the input `1` you would get the int value 1.

So the value you now have is an int and not a string. It does not have a method `isdigit`. If you are sticking with python 2, you should instead use `raw_input`, which doesnt do the `eval` and therefore always returns a string, which has an `isdigit` method.

For python3 `input` does what `raw_input` does it py2 and so works correctly here.