# Detecting if input is int or str • Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7

**EDIT:***This has been solved!*

Im programming a program that will tell you if you are old enough to vote. And, when it asks you for your age, I want it to say a certain thing if the user types letters instead of a number, something like "Please enter a number, not a letter. Restart." Here is the code I have right now:

```
name = raw_input("What is your name?: ")
print("")
print("Hello, "+name+".\n")
print("Today we will tell you if you are old enough to vote.")
age = input("How old are you?: ")
if age >= 18:
    print("You are old enough to vote, "+name+".")
elif age < 18:
    print("Sorry, but you are not old enough to vote, "+name+".")
```

Comment: I suggest you to use string formatting, i.e. replace all those `'Hello, ' + name + '.'` with `'Hello, %s.' % name`. Here's a good tutorial for string formatting: https://pyformat.info/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try something like this :

```
name = raw_input("What is your name?: ")
print("")
print("Hello, "+name+".\n")
print("Today we will tell you if you are old enough to vote.")
while True:
    try:
        #get the input to be an integer.
        age = int(raw_input("How old are you?: "))
        #if it is you break out of the while
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("Please enter a number, not a letter. Restart.")
if age >= 18:
    print("You are old enough to vote, "+name+".")
elif age < 18:
    print("Sorry, but you are not old enough to vote, "+name+".")
```

Comment: I tried this, but I got an error: Traceback (most recent call last):   File "vote.py", line 8, in <module>     age = int(input("How old are you?: "))   File "<string>", line 1, in <module> NameError: name 'Dhbe' is not defined

Comment: change `input` to `raw_input`

Answer (score 0):

```
name = raw_input("What is your name?: ")
print("")
print("Hello, "+name+".\n")
print("Today we will tell you if you are old enough to vote.")
while True:
    age = raw_input("How old are you?: ")
    try:
        age = int(age)
    except ValueError:
        print("Please enter a number, not a letter. Restart.")
    else:
        break
if age >= 18:  
    print("You are old enough to vote, "+name+".")
elif age < 18:    # else:
    print("Sorry, but you are not old enough to vote, "+name+".")
```

In the `try-except-else`, we try to convert age from string to integer. If an `ValueError` occurs, it means that the input string isn't a legal integer. If not, then we can simply jump out the `while` loop and do the following task.

Note1: better don't use `input()` in python2. Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4960208/python-2-7-getting-user-input-and-manipulating-as-string-without-quotations).

Note2: `elif` is useless. Simply use `else`.

Comment: I can't figure out how to fit that into the code. D:

Comment: edited: complete the example and add some explanation.

Comment: You probably meant `try-except-else` instead of `try-catch-else` ^^

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen you got me. Thanks :)