# How to receive input and print it using Python?

Tags: python-2.7

I have written the following code:

```
name = input("What is your name: ")
print(name)
```

It is giving the below error when I input my name

> /usr/bin/python2.7 /home/sreedhar/PycharmProjects/Sample1/sample.py
>   What is your name: Sree Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/sreedhar/PycharmProjects/Sample1/sample.py", line 1, in
>   
>       name = input("What is your name: ")   File "", line 1, in  NameError: name 'Sree' is not defined
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

Can some body help me debug this code, I have started python today. And I'm using python community 17.2 on Linux mint for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `raw_input`instead:

```
name = raw_input("What is your name: ")
print(name)
```

see [Python 2.7 getting user input and manipulating as string without quotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4960208/python-2-7-getting-user-input-and-manipulating-as-string-without-quotations)

`input` works on python 3.x, not in 2.x