# User Input crashing import GUI

Tags: python, user-interface

I am trying to prompt the user for their name so it can be displayed in the GUI of the program I am building for Uni, problem is the `ttt = ...` won't accept anything other than a string in quotation marks without crashing.

My code looks like this:

```
import tic_tac_toe_gui
import tkinter
# The object of the TicTacToeGUI class
# that renders the GUI.
# You can use this object to access the
# methods listed in the specification.

display_details() #displays author's details

name = input("Please enter your name here: ")
ttt = tic_tac_toe_gui.TicTacToeGUI(name) #defining GUI title bar
```

By my understanding, it should take the input, assign the string to the variable and thus allowing the user input to be displayed in the GUI.

NOTE: Cannot edit the GUI as it was built by the tutor.

Let me know if you'd like to see the GUI code.

Comment: provide your stack trace

Comment: what do you meanwhat do you mean "By my understanding it should implement the User input into the GUI" ???

Comment: that the input should be put into the loop in the GUI.

Comment: Edited for better understanding, thanks guys

Comment: @NinjaRawr see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4960208/python-2-7-getting-user-input-and-manipulating-as-string-without-quotations/4960216#4960216