# NameError Using Input - Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, nameerror

I have made a script for checking if a variable is the same as an input variable:

```
def password():
    userPassword = str(input("Type Your Password: "))
    if userPassword == storedPassword:
        print 'Access Granted'
    else:
        print 'Access Denied'
        password()
```

However whenever I type a letter for the input, it throws a NameError, but it works fine with numbers.

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\***\Desktop\Test\Script.py", line 16, in <module>
    password()
  File "C:\Users\***\Desktop\Test\Script.py", line 9, in password
    userPassword = str(input("Type Your Password: "))
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'f' is not defined
```

Comment: You're going to need to fix the indentation in the question before anyone can help you.

Comment: Oops, Thanks didn't see that :)

Comment: its running fine on my machine..

Comment: Is it that you forgot to specify storedPassword in the context?

Comment: Please update your answer to include the complete error.

Comment: No, I do have storedPassword, I just haven't included it.

Comment: Use `raw_input` instead of `input`.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll try that

Comment: I'm glad to hear it :) Please remember to mark my answer as accepted.

Comment: Will do when it allows me :P

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python 2.7 getting user input and manipulating as string without quotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4960208/python-2-7-getting-user-input-and-manipulating-as-string-without-quotations)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `raw_input` instead of `input` on python 2.

Using `input` attempts to evaulate whatever you pass it. In the case of an integer it just resolves to that integer. In the case of a string, it'll attempt to find that variable name and that causes your error.

You can confirm this by typing a 'password' such as password which would have your input call return a reference to your `password` function.

Conversely, `raw_input` always returns a string containing the characters your user typed. Judging by your attempt to cast whatever the user types back into a string, this is exactly what you want.

```
userPassword = raw_input("Type Your Password: ")
```

Answer (score 0):

For Python 2.7 you need to use `raw_input()` instead of `input()`, `input()` actually evaluates the input as Python code. `raw_input()` returns the verbatim string entered by the user.

See [Python 2.7 getting user input and manipulating as string without quotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4960208/python-2-7-getting-user-input-and-manipulating-as-string-without-quotations)