# Using writelines and append to create a file not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, append, console.writeline

I am trying to create a file that just writes the user's name to a file. I have written:

```
def main():
    f=open("name.txt","a")
    name=input("name:")
    f.writelines(name)
    f.close()
main()
```

I am wondering what I am missing in order for this to work because it does not save into a text file. Additionally I am using append so I can run this program more than once and continuously add names to it.

Comment: f.close should be a method call `f.close()`

Comment: Thanks for the catch, unfortunately it still does not save

Comment: try to do flush before close like `f.flush()`

Comment: f.flush() still does not work

Comment: do u have access to write directly in the current directory?

Comment: @BarbaraJ Code works for me; please explain "does not save into a text file" ? -- does it create the file ? (if not: are you looking in the right directory) -- what happens if you change to a full path for the file, example: `f=open(r"c:\somedir\name.txt","a")` ?

Answer (score 0):

The code works fine, but I suspect why it doesn't for you.

In the console, using `input` function, you need to tell the program that you're sending him a string.
When it asks for the name, you shouldn't input for instance `Bernard`, but `"Bernard"`.

You should use `raw_input` instead if you want to get rid of the `"` character.

PS : Have you tried running your program in the console using python command ? You would have seen the error message pop.

Comment: Even when I input "Bernard" with the quotations it still doesn't save. I also have python 3 so raw_input is just input for me

Comment: I do not have python 3.x installed. Your script does work for me in Python 2.7 though.

Try doing `f.write(name)` instead of `f.writelines(name)` ?

Comment: f.write(name) still does not save my file unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

`input` is used to read integers.

Use `raw_input` instead. A lot of people don't recommend using input.

It is possible a duplicate: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4960208/python-2-7-getting-user-input-and-manipulating-as-string-without-quotations)

Comment: I have python 3.x so raw_input is not a function for me

Comment: Ops, didn't see it.. Anyway, just installed python 3.6.3 to give it a go, and your code works fine. What is the exception ? Or it just don't create/save the file ?

Comment: It just does not create and save the file

Comment: Have you tried to set a path for the file to be saved ? (I'm assuming you are running windows) Something like:
path = "C:/Users/<your_user>/Desktop/name.txt" and then f = open(path, "a")
Otherwise it will created the file in the dir you are running the .py