# Python-Dictionary states and capital game

Tags: python, dictionary

I created a game to guess US States and Capitals. It works in Jupyter Notebook. When I save the code to game.py and run it in Windows CMD, my code does not loop 10 times, but just one time, then the CMD will close automatically. Any reason why?

Also, I used  random.choice function to randomly select 10 states, how do I avoid duplicate? I want 10 separate states each time I run my code.

Thank you!

```
import random

capital_dic={
    'Alabama': 'Montgomery',
    'Alaska': 'Juneau',
    'Arizona':'Phoenix',
    'Arkansas':'Little Rock',
    'California': 'Sacramento',
    'Colorado':'Denver',
    'Connecticut':'Hartford',
    'Delaware':'Dover',
    'Florida': 'Tallahassee',
    'Georgia': 'Atlanta',
    'Hawaii': 'Honolulu',
    'Idaho': 'Boise',
    'Illinios': 'Springfield',
    'Indiana': 'Indianapolis',
    'Iowa': 'Des Monies',
    'Kansas': 'Topeka',
    'Kentucky': 'Frankfort',
    'Louisiana': 'Baton Rouge',
    'Maine': 'Augusta',
    'Maryland': 'Annapolis',
    'Massachusetts': 'Boston',
    'Michigan': 'Lansing',
    'Minnesota': 'St. Paul',
    'Mississippi': 'Jackson',
    'Missouri': 'Jefferson City',
    'Montana': 'Helena',
    'Nebraska': 'Lincoln',
    'Neveda': 'Carson City',
    'New Hampshire': 'Concord',
    'New Jersey': 'Trenton',
    'New Mexico': 'Santa Fe',
    'New York': 'Albany',
    'North Carolina': 'Raleigh',
    'North Dakota': 'Bismarck',
    'Ohio': 'Columbus',
    'Oklahoma': 'Oklahoma City',
    'Oregon': 'Salem',
    'Pennsylvania': 'Harrisburg',
    'Rhoda Island': 'Providence',
    'South Carolina': 'Columbia',
    'South Dakoda': 'Pierre',
    'Tennessee': 'Nashville',
    'Texas': 'Austin',
    'Utah': 'Salt Lake City',
    'Vermont': 'Montpelier',
    'Virginia': 'Richmond',
    'Washington': 'Olympia',
    'West Virginia': 'Charleston',
    'Wisconsin': 'Madison',
    'Wyoming': 'Cheyenne'  
} # create a dictionary, key is the state and value is the capital
States=list(capital_dic.keys())
print ('Let\'s learn US States and Capitals. 10 rounds. Enter exit to quit the game.')
point=0 # this is the score
for i in range(10):
    state=random.choice(States) # randomly select 10 states, how do I avoid duplicate?
    capital = capital_dic[state]
    user_guess = input('what is the capital of %s?'%state )
    if user_guess.lower() == 'exit':  #if a user type in exit, the game exits
        break
    elif user_guess.title() == capital:
        point+=1
        print('Correct! Your score is %d' %point)
    else:
        print('Incorrect. The capital of {} is {}.'.format(state,capital))
print('We are done. Your final score is %d, thank you.' %point)
```

Comment: You can use `random_states = random.sample(States, 10)` to pick 10 random states. I don't know what you mean about your code not looping: it does loop.

Comment: Just came here looking for a dictionary of US states. thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem with looping was that you are using `python2` in your windows cmd. `input` function is little bit different from `python3` version, so try to use `raw_input` function if you want to run this code with `python2`:

```
user_guess = raw_input('what is the capital of %s?' % state)
```

see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4960208/python-2-7-getting-user-input-and-manipulating-as-string-without-quotations#answer-4960216) for details

Comment: Yes, i see! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use `random.sample` to get unique set of random names.

**Ex:**

```
States=list(capital_dic.keys())
print random.sample(States, 10)
```

**Output:**

```
['Michigan', 'Alabama', 'Virginia', 'Massachusetts', 'Rhoda Island', 'Kentucky', 'Louisiana', 'Wyoming', 'Arizona', 'Vermont']
```

Snippet Update:

```
for state in random.sample(States, 10):
    capital = capital_dic[state]
```

Comment: Shall I ditch the for loop, just use random.sample(States, 10)?

Comment: You can update your loop to iterate over the random.sample list

Comment: Great! Let me try that. Thank you!