# Python 3: How do I make a game using user input and retrieving answer from a list of dictionaries, then use a point system?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, random, points

I'm trying to make a game where the user is asked to guess a country based on it's capital which is selected at random from a list of dictionaries (similar to the link at bottom).

Guessing 10 countries in total, if they guess correctly they get 1 point, with 10 points in total.

I've imported a variable 'countries' that contains a list of dictionaries like the following:

```
[{'capital': 'Andorra la Vella',
  'code': 'AD',
  'continent': 'Europe',
  'name': 'Andorra',
  'timezones': ['Europe/Andorra']},
 {'capital': 'Kabul',
  'code': 'AF',
  'continent': 'Asia',
  'name': 'Afghanistan',
  'timezones': ['Asia/Kabul']},
```

So how do I print a random choice from a specific key name? In this case, any 'capital' from any of the dictionaries.

[Python-Dictionary states and capital game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49193164/python-dictionary-states-and-capital-game)

Comment: something like `import random   print(capitals[random.randint(0, len(capitals) - 1)]['capital'])`  assuming `capitals`is the list you have given.
edit: much simplier with `random.choice()` actually. Thanks @Jeppe !

Comment: Simply use [`random.choice()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306400/how-to-randomly-select-an-item-from-a-list), which gives you a random dictionary. You can then fetch the capital from the returned dictionary and access the country when you check the user-input.

Comment: @rene-d The [implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/random.py#L278) of `random.choice()` actually looks pretty much like your code.

Comment: @LaurenToulson Great - welcome to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`random.choice` is very good for this use case :)

```
import random


country_dlist = [{'capital': 'Andorra la Vella',
  'code': 'AD',
  'continent': 'Europe',
  'name': 'Andorra',
  'timezones': ['Europe/Andorra']},
 {'capital': 'Kabul',
  'code': 'AF',
  'continent': 'Asia',
  'name': 'Afghanistan',
  'timezones': ['Asia/Kabul']}
 ]

def run():
    tot_points = 0
    num_of_ques = len(country_dlist)
    for i in range(num_of_ques):
        choice = random.choice(country_dlist)
        que = country_dlist.remove(choice)
        capital = raw_input("Please enter the captial for country {}: ".format(choice['name']))
        if capital.lower() == choice['capital'].lower(): # case insensitive match :)
            tot_points += 1
    return tot_points

points = run()
print("You scored {} points".format(points))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below two options.

1. [random.choice](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) to
   select a random element from a the list.

Sample code.

```
from random import choice
country_dict = [{'capital': 'Andorra la Vella',     'code': 'AD',  continent': 'Europe',      'name': 'Andorra',      'timezones': 'Europe/Andorra']},
                {'capital': 'Kabul',      'code': 'AF',      'continent': 'Asia',      ame': 'Afghanistan',      'timezones': ['Asia/Kabul']}
               ]
country = choice(country_dict)
capital = input("Please enter the captial for country "+country['name'])
if capital == country['capital']:
    print("Correct answer")
```

2. [random.ranint](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html) to select random integer between 0 and length of list.

Sample code:

```
from random import randint
country_dict = [{'capital': 'Andorra la Vella',      'code': 'AD',      'continent': 'Europe',      'name': 'Andorra',      'timezones': ['Europe/Andorra']},
                {'capital': 'Kabul',      'code': 'AF',      'continent': 'Asia',      'name': 'Afghanistan',      'timezones': ['Asia/Kabul']}
               ]
ind = randint(0,len(country_dict)-1)
capital = input("Please enter the captial for country "+country_dict[ind]['name'])
if capital == country_dict[ind]['capital']:
    print("Correct answer")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch a random sample with [`randomCountry = random.choice(countries)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice)

However, if you do this multiple times, you may get the same country multiple times. To combat this, you could sample 10 distinct elements with [`randomCountries = random.sample(countries, 10)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample) and then iterate with those.

Note that `random.sample` throws an error if you attempt to sample more elements than there exists in the collection.

Your game could thus look like this:

```
import random

countries = [
    {'capital': 'Andorra la Vella', 'code': 'AD', 'continent': 'Europe', 'name': 'Andorra', 'timezones': ['Europe/Andorra']}, 
    {'capital': 'Kabul', 'code': 'AF', 'continent': 'Asia', 'name': 'Afghanistan', 'timezones': ['Asia/Kabul']},
    ...
]

rounds = 10
random_countries = random.sample(countries, rounds) # returns 10 random elements (no duplicates)

score = 0
for country in random_countries:
    print("Score: %d / %d | Which country has the capital: %s?" % (score, rounds, country['capital']))
    country_response = input()
    if country_response == country['name']:
        score += 1
        print("Correct")
    else:
        print("Incorrect")
```

Answer (score -2):

like this?

```
import random
place_list = [{'capital': 'Andorra la Vella', 'code': 'AD', 'continent': 'Europe', 'name': 'Andorra', 'timezones': ['Europe/Andorra']}, {'capital': 'Kabul', 'code': 'AF', 'continent': 'Asia', 'name': 'Afghanistan', 'timezones': ['Asia/Kabul']}]
quiz_length = 10
points = 0
for q in random.sample(place_list, quiz_length):
    guess = input(f'this place has {q['capital']} in it')
    if guess == q['name']:
        points += 1
print(f'you got {points}/{quiz_length}')
```

edit: the rest of the code...

Comment: posted by accident while typing