# Python split on comma without parenthesis

Tags: python, split

I have a question regarding Python syntax.

When parsing a string and casting it to a float, I am running in to an issue.

I have the code

```
print "Please enter in x1 and y1 separated by a comma"
in1 = input()
sp1 = str(in1).split(',')

x1 = sp1[0]
```

If I enter in

```
5.4,3.2
```

and print out x1, I get

```
(5.4
```

This extra parenthesis makes it hard for me to convert into a floating point for further calculation.
However, if I split based on a a decimal, such as

```
print "Please enter in x1 and y1 separated by a comma"
    in1 = input()
    sp1 = str(in1).split('.')
```

I am able to print x1 as

```
5
```

I do not get the parenthesis which is good, however I am not getting the correct number either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you

Comment: I followed your steps and cannot reproduce the issue. When entering `5.4,3.2`, splitting the string at `,` and assigning the first part to x1, x1 is `5.4` for me (Python 3.6)

Comment: As mentioned here `input()` evaluates what you enter as Python code and then thinks it's a tuple because of the comma. Use `raw_input()`. https://stackoverflow.com/a/4960216/102315

Comment: Any reason you want to convert to `str` first and then extract the number? Python has done it for you already, so you can just do `x1, y1 = in1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be that `input()` evaluates the expression and returns whatever got evaluated. `5.4,3.2` seems to be evaluated to a tuple.

The solution is to use `raw_input()` instead, which will just return the inputted text as a string. Or use Python 3, if possible, which changed `input()` to do what `raw_input()` does for Python 2.

Comment: this explaination is gooooood

Comment: That seemed to do it! Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Looks like when submitting a value in input with a comma you get a tuple. Instead of converting it to a string & splitting it access the element directly using index.

**Ex:**

```
print "Please enter in x1 and y1 separated by a comma"
sp1 = input()
print sp1, type(sp1)
x1 = sp1[0]
print x1
```

**Output:**

```
(5.4, 3.2) <type 'tuple'>
5.4
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do this :

```
print ("Please enter in x1 and y1 separated by a comma : ")
in1 = input()
sp1 =" ".join(str(in1).split(','))
print(sp1)
```

**intput**

1.1,1.2

**output**

1.1 1.2