# Value error storing user input Integer into an array in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm creating an application for my programming class and I'm unable to get it to run properly. Essentially, the application should take 8 numbers from the user and store them in an array and then add those numbers. However, if the user does not provide a number, or press Q, the program should stop.

```
userNumberList = []
counter = 0
while counter < 8:

    try:
        userNumber = int(input("Welcome! Please provide numbers or press q to quit. "))
    except ValueError:
        print("Not a number. Closing application.")
        break
    else:
        if userNumber == 'q':
            break
        else:
            userNumberList.append(int(userNumber))
            counter += 1

print(sum(userNumberList))
```

This is the error I get when running typing a String instead of a number in the prompt:

```
userNumber = int(input("Welcome! Please provide numbers or press q to quit. "))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:
```

Comment: I feel like we need a canonical question specifically about trying to convert the letter `q` to an int...

Comment: Anyway, the code you posted doesn't throw that exception. Your indentation is wrong (the code throws a SyntaxError), and if I fix that then the ValueError is caught correctly. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Please can you fix the indentation? I can't see why you'd get that error. Also, we can use a full traceback here.

Comment: Code has been indented. Sorry about that.

Comment: Even with your indentation fixed I don't get that.

Comment: `int(input( ` cast the int later in the process.

Comment: And use `raw_input` over `input`. Tested it out, works a treat.
`userNumber = raw_input("Welcome! Please provide numbers or press q to quit. ")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:
Do not convert to int before checking to q.

```
userNumberList = []
counter = 0
while counter < 8:
    userNumber = input("Welcome! Please provide numbers or press q to quit. ")
    if userNumber == 'q':
        print("Entered command to quit!! closing the application")
        break
    else:
        try:
            userNumberList.append(int(userNumber))
            counter += 1
        except ValueError:
            print("Not a number. Closing application.")
            break
print(sum(userNumberList))
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! When I run it and type Q to quit or provide a String instead of an int, I get the error:  `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: `

Answer (score 0):

Don't cast the input to an `int` straight away. You're handling that when appending anyway.

And apprently `input` evaluates input as python code. Use `raw_input` instead. This answer may be helpful [Python 2.7 getting user input and manipulating as string without quotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4960208/python-2-7-getting-user-input-and-manipulating-as-string-without-quotations?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

```
userNumber = raw_input("Welcome! Please provide numbers or press q to quit. ")
```

Changing this line fixes the program.

Comment: This is not an answer. The question is tagged as Python3 and seemingly the code is Python3. `raw_input` is not defined in Python3.

Comment: @Mr.T its also tagged with `python`, the code 'works' with that line amended. Your comment might be friendly/helpful mentioning that `raw_input` was renamed to `input` in python3