# How to make python read input as a float?

Tags: python

I need to take an input in the following form "score/max" (Example 93/100) and store it as a float variable. The problem I run into is that python does the division indicated by backslash and since the two numbers are integers, the result is 0. Even if I convert my input into a float the result is 0.0.
Here is my code for reference:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

exam1=float(input("Input the first test score in the form score/max:"))
```

If 93/100 is entered, exam1 variable will be equal to 0.0 instead of the intended 0.93.

Comment: Keep in mind that you need to handle the 'Divide by zero error'

Comment: `93/100` is not a float. It you calculate its result then it can be interpreted as a float.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note:**

### `input()`

> reads a line from input, converts it to a string
>   (stripping a trailing newline), and returns that.

You may want to try the following code,

```
string = input("Input the first test score in the form score/max: ")
scores = string.strip().split("/")
exam1 = float(scores[0]) / float(scores[1])

print(exam1)
```

Input:

```
Input the first test score in the form score/max: 93/100
```

Output:

```
0.93
```

Comment: The code you have provided does not work. The error that I get is the following: AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'strip'
I am using python 2.7 if that helps.

Comment: if you are using python 2.7 just replace `input` with `raw_input`

Answer (score 1):

You could use python's `fractions` module, which knows how to read a fraction string

```py
from fractions import Fraction
exam1 = float(Fraction(input("Input the first test score in the form score/max:")))
```

for Python 2.7, use `raw_input` instead of `input`

see [Python 2.7 getting user input and manipulating as string without quotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4960208/python-2-7-getting-user-input-and-manipulating-as-string-without-quotations)

```
Input the first test score in the form score/max:93/100
>>> exam1
0.93
```

Comment: I still get 0.0 as my answer. I am using python 2.7 if that helps.

Comment: @Dante in python 2.7, use `raw_input` instead of `input` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4960208/python-2-7-getting-user-input-and-manipulating-as-string-without-quotations