# How to calculate growth yield of an investment on maturity in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to calculate growth yield of an investment on maturity. My data is as follows:

[image]

My code is as follows

```
a = input('principal amount\n')
principal=float(s)
a = input('prime rate\n')
prime=float(s)
a = input('number of years\n')
numberofyears=float(a)
if numberofyears <= 2:
  if principal <= 100000:
    growth = principal*prime
    print(growth)
  elif principal > 100000:
    growth = principal * (prime + (1.25 * prime))
    print(growth)
elif numberofyears <= 4:
  if principal <= 100000:
    growth = principal*(1.15*prime)
    print(growth)
  elif principal > 100000:
    growth = principal * ((1.15*prime) + (1.5 * prime))
    print(growth)
elif numberofyears > 4:
  if principal <= 100000:
    growth = principal*(1.25*prime)
    print(growth)
  elif principal > 100000:
    growth = principal * ((1.25*prime) + (2 * prime))
    print(growth)
```

What is wrong with my code? because when i put example data output is not as mentioned.

For example:

[image]

Output i am getting is 33125.0

Comment: Can you please show some of your output and highlight the issue with the output?

Comment: @KindStranger kindly check it

Comment: " Kindly tell me what is wrong with my code " For the cases the principal is larger than 10e6, the equations in your code is diffrerent the ones in the images.

Comment: @kubatucka what could be the equation?

Comment: Make sure to only use `raw_input()` instead of `input()` in python2.7. See this post for more detail
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4960208/python-2-7-getting-user-input-and-manipulating-as-string-without-quotations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 mistakes in your code. First your principal and your prime are assigned to the float of s which is not the the input. Then your equations don't apply the different rates for <=10e6 and >10e6.

Here's one way of doing it:

```
principal=float(input('principal amount\n'))
prime=float(input('prime rate\n') )
numberofyears=float(input('number of years\n') )
if numberofyears <= 2:
 if principal <= 100000:
   growth = principal*prime
   print(growth)
 elif principal > 100000:
   growth = 1000000* (prime) + (principal-100000)*(1.25*prime)
   print(growth)
elif numberofyears <= 4:
 if principal <= 100000:
   growth = principal*(1.15*prime)
   print(growth)
 elif principal > 100000:
   growth = 1000000*(1.15*prime) + (principal-100000)*(1.5*prime)
   print(growth)
elif numberofyears > 4:
 if principal <= 100000:
   growth = principal*(1.25*prime)
   print(growth)
 elif principal > 100000:
   growth = 1000000*(1.25*prime) + (principal-100000)*(2*prime)
   print(growth)
```